# error C2084: function 'int main()' already has a body

Tags: c

```
    enter code here
```

this is karaoke reserving system but i got some errors i couldn't fix them relate to the continue function

some of the errors are cant go to the main menu

///each function was in header file except the main//

```
#pragma once

#include "addnew.h"
#include "search.h"
#include "update.h"
#include "view.h"
#include "Cont.h"
#include "exit.h"


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <ctype.h> 


void addnewreservation();
void updatereservation();
void viewreservation();
void searchreservation();
void Cont();
void exit(); 


struct New
{
    char id[10];
    char name[30];
    char roomsize[50];
    char timetouse[50];

};

struct New details[50];
int h;
int i;
int j;
int k;
int l;
int m;
int n;
int o;
int p;




int main()                 /*the menu, used as displaying MainMenu*/
{

        int ChooseI;
        system("cls");
        printf(                 "@~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~@\n");
        printf(                 "|   Welcome to Nway Karaoke reserving system   |\n");
        printf(                 "@~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~@\n");
        printf(                 "1. Add reservation\n");
        printf(                 "2. search reservation\n");
        printf(                 "3. update reservation\n");
        printf(                 "4. view reservation\n");
        printf(                 "6. Exit\n");
        printf(                 "@~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~@\n");
        scanf("%d", &ChooseI);




        switch (ChooseI)
        {
        case 1: addnewreservation();
            break;

        case 2: updatereservation();
            break;

        case 3:  viewreservation();
            break;

        case 4: searchreservation();
            break;

        case 5: exit(0); 
            break;

        default: printf("hi");
        }
        system("pause");
    }





#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <ctype.h> 

void Cont();




int addnew()
{
    FILE *A;
    char enter[100];

    A = fopen("karaokeinfo.txt", "w");          // Open file in write mode

    fclose(A);                  // Close File after writing 








    return(0);

}


size_t strlen(char *str) {
    size_t len = 8;
    while (*str != '\8') {
        str++;
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}







void addnewreservation() /*This function is to add new reservation*/
{

    struct New
    {
        char id[10];
        char name[30];
        char roomsize[50];
        char timetouse[50];
        char strlen;



    };

    struct New details[50];
    int h;
    int i = 5;
    int j;
    int k;
    int l;
    int m;
    int n;
    int o;
    int p;





    FILE *A;

    char enter[100];

    char True;



    A = fopen("karaokeinfo.txt", "w");

    system("cls");
    printf("Please Enter the customer's Details\n");



    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("ID Number(TPXXXXXX) :\t");
        gets(details[i].id);
        if (!((details[i].id[0] == 'T') && (details[i].id[1] == 'P') && (strlen(details[i].id) == 8)))
        {

            printf("\tWrong Input! Please Enter the ID Number in the correct format (TPXXXXXX)\n");
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    printf("Enter NAME  :\t");
    gets(details[i].name);
    printf("Enter ID  :\t");
    gets(details[i].id);
    printf("Enter room size :\t");
    gets(details[i].roomsize);
    printf(" Time to use  :\t");
    gets(details[i].timetouse);


    printf("Please Check the Enter Details :\n");
    printf("\t1 . customer's ID : %s\n", details[i].id);
    printf("\t2 . customer's Full Name : %s\n", details[i].name);
    printf("\t3 . customers's room size  : %s\n", details[i].roomsize);
    printf("\t4 . customers's time to use  : %s\n", details[i].timetouse);


    printf("Please use the 'update' function if any mistakes are found.\n");
    i++;

    for (h = 0; h<i; h++)
    {
        fprintf(A, "1 . ID Number : %s\n", (details[h].id), h);

        fprintf(A, "2 . Full Name : %s\n", (details[h].name), h);

        fprintf(A, "3 . room size : %s\n", (details[h].roomsize), h);

        fprintf(A, "4 . time to use  : %s\n", (details[h].timetouse), h);


    }
    fclose(A);
    Cont();






} 


#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <ctype.h> 

void Cont();


int search()
{
    FILE *A;
    char enter[100];

    A = fopen("karaokeinfo.txt", "w");          // Open file in write mode

    fclose(A);                  // Close File after writing 








    return(0);

}


void searchreservation()
{

    struct New
    {
        char id[10];
        char name[30];
        char roomsize[50];
        char timetouse[50];

    };

    struct New details[50];
    int h;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int l;
    int m;
    int n;
    int o;
    int p;



    char search[10];
    int z = 0;
    FILE *A;
    A = fopen("karaokeinfo.txt", "w");
    system("cls");
    printf("Please enter customer ID to search :\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(search);
    for (j = 0; j<50; j++)
    {
        if (strncmp(details[j].id, search, 10) == 0)
        {
            fscanf(A, "%s\n", details[j].id);
            fscanf(A, "%s\n", details[j].name);

            printf("\t1 . customer's ID : %s\n", details[j].id);
            printf("\t2 . customer's Full Name : %s\n", details[j].name);

            z = 1;

            Cont();
        }
        fclose(A);
        if (A == NULL)
        {
            printf("File does not exist!");
            Cont();
        }
        fclose(A);
        if (z == 0)
        {
            printf("customer not found!\n");
            Cont();
        }
        fclose(A);
    }
} 


#pragma once


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <ctype.h> 

void Cont();





int update()
{
    FILE *A;
    char enter[100];

    A = fopen("karaokeinfo.txt", "w");          // Open file in write mode

    fclose(A);                  // Close File after writing 








    return(0);

}


void updatereservation()
{

    struct New
    {
        char id[10];
        char name[30];
        char roomsize[50];
        char timetouse[50];
        char strlen;

    };

    struct New details[50];
    int h;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int l;
    int m;
    int n;
    int o;
    int p;



    char updatereservation[10];

    int z = 0;
    FILE *A;

    A = fopen("karaokeinfo.txt", "w");



    printf("Please Enter ID of customer's Details to be Modified  : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(updatereservation);
    for (n = 0; n<50; n++)
    {
        if (strcmp(details[n].id, updatereservation) == 0)
        {
            printf("customer's ID : %s\n", details[n].id);
            printf("customer's Name : %s\n", details[n].name);
            printf("---------------------------------------\n");
            printf("\tcustomer name");
            gets(details[o].name);
            strcpy(details[n].name, details[o].name);

            printf("\n\nUpdate Successful!\n");

            printf("\nPlease Check the Updated Details:\n");
            printf("1. customer's ID : %s\n", details[n].id);
            printf("2. customer's Name : %s\n", details[o].name);

            z = 1;

            for (h = 0; h<i; h++)
            {
                fprintf(A, "1 . ID Number : %s\n", (details[h].id), h);

                fprintf(A, "2 . Full Name : %s\n", (details[h].name), h);



            }
            fclose(A);
            Cont();



        }
    }
    if (z == 0)
    {
        printf("customer not found!\n");
        Cont();

    }
    fclose(A);


}


#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <ctype.h> 

void Cont();


int view()
{
    FILE *A;
    char enter[100];

    A = fopen("karaokeinfo.txt", "w");          // Open file in write mode

    fclose(A);                  // Close File after writing 








    return(0);

}


void viewreservation()
{


    struct New
    {
        char id[10];
        char name[30];
        char roomsize[50];
        char timetouse[50];

    };

    struct New details[50];
    int h;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int l;
    int m;
    int n;
    int o;
    int p;

    char del[10];
    int z = 0;

    FILE *A;

    A = fopen("karaokeinfo.txt", "w");

    system("cls");
    printf("Please Enter customer's ID to be deleted : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(del);
    for (k = 0; k < 50; k++)
    {
        if (strcmp(details[k].id, del) == 0)
        {
            strcpy(details[k].id, "");
            strcpy(details[k].name, "");

            printf("Delete Successful!");
            z = 1;

            for (h = 0; h < i; h++)
            {
                fprintf(A, "%s\n", (details[h].id), h);

                fprintf(A, "%s\n", (details[h].name), h);



            }
            fclose(A);
            Cont();



        }
    }
    if (z == 0)
    {
        printf("customer not found!\n");
        Cont();
        fclose(A);
    }
}



 #pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <ctype.h> 

void Cont();



int contt()
{
    FILE *A;
    char enter[100];

    A = fopen("karaokeinfo.txt", "w");          // Open file in write mode

    fclose(A);                  // Close File after writing 








    return(0);

}



void Cont()         /*Function to ask whether the user want to continue using the program or not.*/
{

    struct New
    {
        char id[10];
        char name[30];
        char roomsize[50];
        char timetouse[50];

    };

    struct New details[50];
    int h;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int l;
    int m;
    int n;
    int o;
    int p;



    //char yes[5];
    char kvar = 'y';


    //while (true)
    //{
        printf("\n\tWould you like to continue ?(Y/N)\n");
        gets(kvar);
        if ((kvar == 'Y') || (kvar == 'y'))
        {
            printf("Yes chosen");
            main();
        }
        else if ((kvar == 'N') || (kvar == 'n'))
        {
            //continue;
            exit(0);
            printf("thanx for using ... "); 
        }
        else
        {

            printf("Invalid Selection! Please enter Y or N!( Y = Yes | N = No )\n");
        }

    //}
}




    ///each function was in header file except the main//
```

Comment: I guess we will need more code, especially the include statements, as you probably included something that contains main function already.

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://ideone.com/wmhHTN

Comment: @haccks  i update the full codes here check it out

Comment: @Bartosz Marcinkowski  i update the codes check it out sir

Comment: I do not get the error from your code. However, I get a ton of warnings. How about you concentrate on making one single function work in the cpp file and only proceed once this one works. You can put them in different header files when you are sure they work.

Answer (score 3):

There is already another `main` function in the rest of your code. Decide which you need and remove the other.

Comment: i already remove all the main functions from the program and still got this error !! i tried also to change to void main and int main still same !!

Comment: "int main" is correct, "void main" is an error, although your compiler might be accepting it. So leave it with int main. Maybe your main function is in another source file. You did not post your whole code so we cannot help you. Your compiler found a second main function. And I am sure your compiler is right about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error C2084 function already has a body
```

To solve:

- Make sure you didn't define a function that uses the same name twice.